# cd command has stopped working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

After installing gem files on my system, cd command has stopped working and throws the following error when I try to open any dir

```
     robus@lucy:~$ cd /starterkit
    -bash: cd: /starterkit: No such file or directory
```

please show me how to solve this problem

Comment: Try `cd starterkit` or `cd ./starterkit`

Comment: Is `starterkit` in the root directory or in your home directory or elsewhere?

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie Tried ! Throws the same error

Comment: @jliv902 Its in the HOME directory

Comment: Try `cd ~/starterkit`

Comment: @jliv902 cd ~/starterkit works !! but why !! what happened to cd /starterkit

Comment: @KuldeepBhatt See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` is the root directory, so when you type `cd /starterkit`, you are looking for the directory `starterkit` in the sub-directory `/`. Since `starterkit` is in your `HOME` folder, `cd` will not find it in the `/` directory.

`~` is a shortcut to `/home/robus`. So when you type `cd ~/starterkit`, you are actually doing `cd /home/robus/starterkit`.

Comment: How can I revert this back to cd /starterkit !? I was able to access such way !

Comment: @KuldeepBhatt Try `sudo mv ~/starterkit /starterkit` or `sudo cp ~/starterkit /starterkit` or `sudo ln -s ~/starterkit /starterkit`.

Comment: You can move the directory to your root directory, or make a symbolic link in your root directory which links to the directory in your home directory.

Comment: Any short code to make a symbolic link in root dir linking ALL dir in home dir ?

Comment: @KuldeepBhatt I'm not sure. I would consider asking a new question. In my opinion, if you need to do that, then you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is an [builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) command in bash.

The directory you are trying to cd into most likely just dont exist.

Comment: actually it does exist and it shows in ls -al. with all perfect permission to excess

Comment: Can you post the `ls -al` output?

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/28ujwat.png

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you posted you should be able to `cd` into that directory. There might be a problem if the directory name is followed by one or more spaces. Try doing `cd starter*` and see if you end up in the directory.

Comment: yes it does work